# Изменить балун для меток, найденных при поиске

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Нужно полностью изменить макет балуна. Все советы относятся к меткам, которые создаем сами, а что насчет меток, найденных при поиске?

Answer (score 0):

API Карт позволяет изменять вид результатов поиска по топонимам (провайдер `yandex#map`). Есть [пример в песочнице](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_search_results?from=SO).

При самостоятельном добавлении результата поиска на карту вы можете настроить макет балуна также, как и для собственных меток.

Обратите внимание, что для результатов поиска по организациям кастомизация вывода и отображения результатов будет нарушать условия использования и может привести к блокировке сервиса.